# How to deploy the SQL Scripts to the local database (One click deployment)?

Tags: sql, visual-studio

How to deploy the SQL scripts to the local database (one-click deployment)?

I am trying to get some syntax advice on using osql batch file mode to deploy all .sql files to the mapped database.

Comment: I'm usually using the proper tool that manage the DB for that purpose(SSMS, MySQL Workbench, ...), using a .sql script such as `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS... CREATE PROCEDURE ...`

Comment: Do  you run the script manually ??  or how do you deploy those scripts ..

Comment: Yes, when I need to edit a procedure, I open the SQL file in SSMS (in example) make changes, and run it. I don't know if it's a best practice, but it works pretty well

Comment: I am looking to deploy bunch of .sql files through one click deployment

Comment: You could check out tools like [DbUp](https://dbup.github.io/) or a great many more that offer such functionality

Comment: I will not be able to use third party tools. I will have to write .. some code logic to do so. i was hoping to do through batch script. I am trying to get some samples